# react-native style opacity for parent and child

Tags: react-native

react-native : I have one View and the child of View is an Image , I applied opacity: 0.5 for View and opacity: 0.9 for an Image but it doesn't apply for Image ,the parent opacity is applying for child , the child doesn't take independent opacity

Answer (score 142):

Try changing the opacity using alpha-value of the background color instead. Then it should be possible applying different opacities for children.

For example:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'}}/>
```

Comment: It does the job. The user could mark this as the correct answer :D

Comment: When using the opacity property you are changing the entire opacity of the view you are applying the property on. Any child components will inherit this opacity.

In this case opacity should be applied on the color only. So this should be the correct answer.

Comment: Quite clearly this will only change the opacity of the background and not the element itself, so if the element contains text, or a child element with another background, this will not have anything close to the desired behaviour. Hemanta's answer is the way to go.

Comment: absolutely what I want.

Answer (score 100):

### React-Native 0.60+

There is a new opacity prop that you can pass in:

```
<View style={{opacity: 0.5}} />
```

### React-Native 0.59.x and lower

Like this (with 50% at the end of color hash):

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF50'}} />
```

Or RGBa way:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'}} />
```

Comment: One thing, `50` doesn't indicate `50%`.  see [this](https://hashnode.com/post/understanding-rrggbbaa-color-notation-cisvdr52x088fwt53h1drf6m2). btw chrome's color picker can convert `rgba` values to `rrggbbaa`.

Comment: Can you please provide a source for your 0.60+ answer? `opacity` prop does not seem to be documented: https://reactnative.dev/docs/view

Comment: You can find the documentation in View Style Props: https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props#opacity

Answer (score 28):

In react-native 0.6, you can use the opacity prop on a View. Example:

```
<View opacity={1.0} />

<View opacity={0.5} />
```

1.0 = opaque (alpha == 1.0)

0.0 = clear (alpha == 0.0)

See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.6/view-style-props#opacity

Snack: https://snack.expo.io/S1KjXqe6N

Comment: Correct answer if you are in RN >0.6

Comment: this is a style prop, it won't work like that. And if u add it as a style prop it has the problem mentioned in the first place

Comment: corrent ans but as the above comment says, it's a style prop.

Comment: @Amiratak88 This prop only applies the opacity to the element to which it's passed unlike the style prop.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to display some text with transparent alpha opacity then **I have the best way**, just try.

```
TransparentBG:{
    backgroundColor:  '#00000070',
    color:'#FFFFFF'
  }
```

here, "70" indicates opacity %.
-Thanks

Comment: This is the most correct answer on this post! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is actually the most accurate response. I didn't know that trick. Thank you.

Comment: 70 isn't 70% opacity. It's a hexadecimal scale, where FF is 100%.

Comment: for decimal alpha, use the rgba function, it's available in React Native too, just pass a string like so: `{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)'}` this makes (70% red) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba

Comment: 70% in hex is about `6F`

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `needsOffscreenAlphaCompositing` like this-

```
<View needsOffscreenAlphaCompositing>
...
<View/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the opacity of a view that doesn't recognize the opacity prop (such as a TouchableOpacity), **wrap it in a View first** and [change the opacity prop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45788137/3151675) of that.

```
<View opacity={0.3}>
<TouchableOpacity>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change parent opacity without affecting child, so you should have absolute positioned background. For proper child positioning, you should add an additional container. Check out this snack: snack.expo.io/SkaHLjzr8

```
...
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.card} >
    <View style={styles.background} />
     <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source="..." />
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
...

...
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  background: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    opacity: .5,
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  card: {
    height: 400,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    zIndex: 2,
    opacity: 0.8,
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200
  }
...
```

Comment: It's good to have an explanation but now there's no code, it's better to show both code and an explanation if possible.  (Just trying to help you give an answer people are more likely to accept)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Home my answer has become really helpful.

Comment: @AlexandrDobrovolsky `<View opacity={0.5} />`

Answer (score 0):

### HACK FOR BACKGROUNDS OPACITY

***Use combination of 2 backgroundColor in order to imitate the opacity***

After playing sometimes and be lost on the internet to find a simple solucion, I realized that at the current React-Native Version `V 0.64` the opacity for the backgrounds, at least as it is commonly used for Web Dev just is not suited for React-Native.

### APP

1. Use `ImageBackground` Component --> [DOCS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground):

**Set you background image on the `ImageBackground`**

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { ImageBackground, View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView} from 'react-native';

    const App = () => {
        
    return (

    <ImageBackground style={ mainStyle.background } source={ { uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" } } resizeMode="cover">       
        <ScrollView style={ mainStyle.overlay }> // Here its style will be used as opacity
            <View style={ mainStyle.containerCenter}>
                <View style={ mainStyle.homeTitleWraper}>
                    <Text style={ mainStyle.homeTitle }> Hello WOrld</Text>
                </View>              
            </View>
        </ScrollView>   
    </ImageBackground>
    );};
  export default App;
```

### Style

2. Style, Here the First Child of the Background has to take the whole
   screen size, with style `overlay` it will lay down like a thin blanket on top of the Background, imitating the opacity.

   ```js
    const mainStyle = StyleSheet.create({

    background: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%", 
    },

    overlay: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)' // HERE USE THE LAST DIGIT AS IF IT WERE OPACITY

    },

    containerCenter : {
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingHorizontal: 30,
        marginVertical: 60,

    },

    homeTitleWraper: {
        paddingHorizontal: 40,
        paddingVertical: 100,  

    },

    homeTitle: {
        fontSize: 40,
        fontWeight: "900",
        textAlign: "center",
        textTransform: "uppercase",  
        color: "white",
        fontStyle: "italic",
    },

    containerSmall: {
        marginVertical: 10,
        width: "100%"

    }
   ```