# giving text some opacity with color in react native

Tags: react-native

I am learning react-native, I am trying to give the Text some opacity, I wonder if is it possible in react native. Is there any RGBA for text color in react-native.
Thanks

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147082/react-native-style-opacity-for-parent-and-child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the opacity of a control via styles.

i.e.

```
<Text style={{color: 'red', opacity: 0.5}} >Text here</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

In React Native you can use the opacity prop

Option 1) Directly in the Text

```
<Text style={{color: 'red', opacity: 0.5}} > Text here </Text>
```

Option 2) Within the View

```
<View style={{opacity: 0.5}}> 
 <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Text here</Text> 
 <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>Some more text here</Text> 
</View>
```

In case you are using React Native 0.59.X and lower opacity prop will not work so you may want to use backgroundColor prop to adjust the opacity as below. You will also have the same effect in

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF50'}} > </View> 
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'}} > </ View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found package that manage color & graded color like #tailwindcss use this package

```
npm -i expo-lite-color
```

or

```
yarn add expo-lite-color
```

### Usages

```
import  {  LiteColor  }  from  'expo-lite-color'
```

After importing the package then use

```
LiteColor.BLUE[500]
```

Fore example for react native project

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: LiteColor.GREEN[300], ...}}> 
</View>
```

thanks me later