# "opacity" breaks the shadow on React Native view

Tags: android, react-native, shadow

Explanation: In the code below, the main view has a style `opacity` set to `1` and shadow works perfectly. When I set the `opacity` to `0.6`, shadow makes the view disrupted. Please check the images to see the difference. How do I solve this problem?

Note: I didn't test it on IOS but it looks like this on android.

```
<View
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    opacity: 1,
  }}>
  <View
    style={{
      padding: 20,
      borderRadius: 10,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      shadowColor: '#000',
      elevation: 5,
    }}>
    <Text>Test 123</Text>
  </View>
  <View></View>
</View>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[react-native style opacity for parent and child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147082/react-native-style-opacity-for-parent-and-child)

Comment: Nope, I want opacity to effect the whole view

Comment: Then try putting opacity on child view too (look updated code above)

Comment: It still looks bad because it's adding the opacity to the inner view two times, and it  still looks bad.

Comment: Please check if this will help [react-native style opacity for parent and child](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36149020/10657559)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the main culprit is the `elevation` property, setting a view's `opacity` will render artifacts when child views have `elevation` (see details in [react-native issue #23090](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23090)). You can fix this by:

- Put opacity on the view that have elevation like the previous answer [react-native style opacity for parent and child](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45788137/12405558).
- Use `needsOffscreenAlphaCompositing` as suggested in the issue above. Note that using this flag can be expensive.